# Smoothing/interpolation of a 3D surface colormap

Tags: matlab, interpolation, surface, smoothing, colormap

I'm trying to smooth or interpolate away the "steps" building up to a intensity maximum, and at the same time preserving the shape of the surface so that the estimated width does not get shifted or changed. I have tried interpolating to a higher resolution using 2D spline, but the "steps" are still present and the estimated maxima region changes. Could someone please help me in smoothing/interpolating away those steps to make the surface look more continuous while conserving the surface shape?

As always, many thanks in advance for any advice or help!!

**Uninterpolated**
[image]
**Interpolated**
[image]

**Attempt**

```
conversion = 1/49.0196; % in mm/pixel

new_xData = linspace(xData(1), xData(end), 10*length(xData));
new_yData = linspace(yData(1), yData(end), 10*length(yData)).';
new_zData = interp2(xData, yData, zData, new_xData, new_yData, 'spline');
xData = new_xData; yData = new_yData; zData = new_zData;

h = figure();
surf(xData, yData, zData, 'LineStyle', 'none', 'FaceColor', 'interp');
xlim([xData(1) xData(end)])
ylim([yData(1) yData(end)])
zlim([0 ceil(max(zData(:)))]); 
colormap(jet(4096))
xlabel('mm'); ylabel('mm'); zlabel('ln(Intensity)');
set(gca,'Ydir', 'reverse')
grid on
shading interp
view(3); axis vis3d; camlight; 

% Change x and y tick labels from pixels to mm
addMM = @(x) sprintf('%.1f', x * conversion);
xticklabels(cellfun(addMM,num2cell(xticks'),'UniformOutput',false));
yticklabels(cellfun(addMM,num2cell(yticks'),'UniformOutput',false));

% Find maxium intensity region and plot it
hold on
maxValue = max(zData(:));
[rowsOfMaxes, colsOfMaxes] = find(zData == maxValue);
x_minind = min(colsOfMaxes(:));
x_maxind = max(colsOfMaxes(:));
p = zeros(1, 2);
p(1) = plot3(linspace(xData(x_minind), xData(x_minind), ...
   length(yData)), yData, zData(:, x_minind), 'Linestyle', '-.', ...
   'Color', 'black', 'LineWidth', 2.0);
p(2) = plot3(linspace(xData(x_maxind), xData(x_maxind), ...
   length(yData)), yData, zData(:, x_maxind), 'Linestyle', '-.', ...
   'Color', 'black', 'LineWidth', 2.0);
hold off
legend(p(1), 'Estimated width of maximum intensity', 'Location', 'North')
set(gca, 'FontSize', 14)
```

Comment: I would suggest the use of [griddata](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) instead of `interp2` ... but we cannot show you an example because you did not provide sample data.

Comment: I have already tried griddata using the different interpolation methods, but the results yields the same as before. See [https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/433168-smoothing-interpolation-of-a-3d-surface-colormap](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/433168-smoothing-interpolation-of-a-3d-surface-colormap)  where I have attached the data needed.

Comment: ok I've seen your data, _interpolation_ cannot do anything for you because your underlying data are already stepped. Your only option to have a continuous surface is to _smooth_, but that will modify your surface (by a bit or a lot more depending on the agressivness of the smoothing filter). What is it exactly you do not want to modify ? (or put differently, how much deviation from the original surface can you accept?)

Comment: I wouldn't want my precision to drop more than 0.01 mm, which corresponds to 0.49 pixel in deviation (so lets say 1 pixel/grid point in deviation). But that means that smoothing will approximately have no effect in clearing out those steps or ...? Also, is it possible to treat each column and row separately (regard the surface points as multiple series of "step data") to perform multiple independent fit of the step data in each dimension? Would it be a better approach to estimate a smooth continuous curve for a step function?

Comment: indeed, smoothing will introduce local differences greater than your target. There is no numerical method which can transform a stepped function into a smooth one and retain 100% of information. Your options: (1) accept the visual stepped aspect (after all, this is what you measured, it's the closest to reality). (2) accept slight local errors and smooth away (3) take more measurements = improve the _base_ resolution.

Comment: Then I'll have to go with option (1) this time and option (3) for future experimental measurements. Thank you so much for your response Hoki, sincerely!!